# PROCEDURES using HR database

Tags: sql, plsql, procedure

I want to Write a PROCEDURE that will first print the Employee Number and Salary of an employee (i.e. 7839).
Then it will increase the salary of an employee 7839 (this will be employee
number in the table employee) as per following conditions:

```
Condition-1: If experience is more than 10 years, increase salary by 20%.
Condition-2: If experience is greater than 5 years, increase salary by 10%.
Condition-3: All others will get an increase of 5% in the salary.
```

The program will print the Employee Number and salary before and after the increase
i tried the following steps but not sure how accurate is it..I need to convert it to a PROCEDURE code.

please advise

```
    DECLARE
     veno  emp.empno%type:=&veno;
     vsal  emp.sal%type;
     vexp  number;
BEGIN
    select empno,sal,trunc(to_char(months_between(sysdate,hiredate)/12))into veno,vsal,vexp from emp where empno=veno;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('before update:' ||chr(10)||veno||chr(10)||vsal);
    if vexp>=10 then
        update emp set sal=sal+(sal*.20) where empno=veno; 
        select sal into vsal from emp where empno=veno;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('after update:' ||chr(10)||vsal);
   elsif vexp>=5 then
        update emp set sal=sal+(sal*.10) where empno=veno;
        select sal into vsal from emp where empno=veno;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('after update:' ||chr(10)||vsal);
     else 
        update emp set sal=sal+(sal*.05) where empno=veno;
        select sal into vsal from emp where empno=veno;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('after update:' ||chr(10)||vsal);
   end if;
END;
/
```

Comment: BTW where is `where` condition?

Comment: dont know how to write it

Comment: How about giving us the table names and how they relate to each other?

Comment: it is the HR schema .. I will update the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Try this one else go with RETURNING clause and add an exception block

```
DECLARE
     veno  emp.empno%type:=&veno;
     vsal  emp.sal%type;
     vexp  number;
BEGIN
    select empno,sal,trunc(to_char(months_between(sysdate,hiredate)/12))into veno,vsal,vexp from emp where empno=veno;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('before update:' ||chr(10)||veno||chr(10)||vsal);
    if vexp>=10 then
        update emp set sal=sal+(sal*.20) where empno=veno; 
        select sal into vsal from emp where empno=veno;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('after update:' ||chr(10)||vsal);
   elsif vexp>=5 then
        update emp set sal=sal+(sal*.10) where empno=veno;
        select sal into vsal from emp where empno=veno;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('after update:' ||chr(10)||vsal);
     else 
        update emp set sal=sal+(sal*.05) where empno=veno;
        select sal into vsal from emp where empno=veno;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('after update:' ||chr(10)||vsal);
   end if;
END;
/
```

Comment: Try implementing the same in your procedure @Shak