# convert to PROCEDURE pl/sql

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, procedure

I want to Write a PROCEDURE that will first print the Employee Number and Salary of an employee (i.e. 7839). Then it will increase the salary of an employee 7839 (this will be employee number in the table employee) as per following conditions:

```
Condition-1: If experience is more than 10 years, increase salary by 20%.
Condition-2: If experience is greater than 5 years, increase salary by 10%.
Condition-3: All others will get an increase of 5% in the salary.
```

The program will print the Employee Number and salary before and after the increase i tried the following steps but not sure how accurate is it..

I need to convert it to a PROCEDURE code.

please advise

```
 DECLARE
     veno  emp.empno%type:=&veno;
     vsal  emp.sal%type;
     vexp  number;
BEGIN
    select empno,sal,trunc(to_char(months_between(sysdate,hiredate)/12))into veno,vsal,vexp from emp where empno=veno;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('before update:' ||chr(10)||veno||chr(10)||vsal);
    if vexp>=10 then
        update emp set sal=sal+(sal*.20) where empno=veno; 
        select sal into vsal from emp where empno=veno;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('after update:' ||chr(10)||vsal);
   elsif vexp>=5 then
        update emp set sal=sal+(sal*.10) where empno=veno;
        select sal into vsal from emp where empno=veno;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('after update:' ||chr(10)||vsal);
     else 
        update emp set sal=sal+(sal*.05) where empno=veno;
        select sal into vsal from emp where empno=veno;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('after update:' ||chr(10)||vsal);
   end if;
END;
/
```

Comment: My first thought is that this program would be considered an anonymous block, not a procedure. A procedure is a stored program that can be called by name. Second, while the program isn't pretty it seems like it would work according to the requirements you posted.

Comment: So, do U want to create procedure from your code?

Comment: Yes I want to create a procedure out of my code.. help please

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/32137151/272735 It's more than duplicate - it's identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to change is the `DECLARE` (indicating the start of an anonymous block) to `CREATE PROCEDURE`, with the variable you're currently setting via a substitution variable as a formal argument; so instead of:

```
DECLARE
     veno  emp.empno%type:=&veno;
     vsal  emp.sal%type;
     vexp  number;
BEGIN
...
END;
/
```

Make it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_proc (veno IN emp.empno%type)
AS
     vsal  emp.sal%type;
     vexp  number;
BEGIN
...
END;
/
```

You can then call that from an anonymous block, or in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer with the `execute` shorthand:

```
set serveroutput on
execute my_proc(&veno);
```

This example is still using a substitution variable so you'll be promoted for the value to use, but you can pass a number directly too.

[Read more about creating procedures](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_procedure.htm#LNPLS01373) and the types of [parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#LNPLS00806).

You could simplify the code quite a bit to reduce repetition and requerying; look up case expressions and the returning clause. But that's not directly relevant.