# PL/SQL Display salary before and after change

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, cursor

I want to write a PL/SQL block that will print the Employee Number and Salaries of two employees before and after changing it.

Please advise

```
cursor cur is select employees.employee_ID, employees.salary
from employees
where employees.employee_ID=&employee_ID
AND employees.salary= employees.salary

sal number;
emp_ID number(10);

introduction clob;
begin
open cur;
loop
fetch cur into sal,emp_ID;
exit when cur>=2;

introduction := '  Display the Employees_ID and Salary before and after change.';
dbms_output.put_line(introduction);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('employee_id =' || emp_ID);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Salary =' || Sal);

end loop;
close cur;
END;
```

Comment: That seems very similar to what you were doing [in your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32147986/266304). What have you tried and what problems do you have adapting that?

Comment: tried cursor but didnt work out well with me

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have tried and why it didn't work. If you got errors then show those, If it gave the wrong results show what you got and what you expected. We can't write the whole thing for you from scratch.

Comment: Question Updated with my code.. Please advise

Answer (score 0):

You need a new column in Employee's table and use it to store old salary in it.

You also need an insert and an update trigger for Salary column to store the current value in the new column you just added earlier.

Now you just need to use a simple select from employee's table to do the job.

Since I dont know your tables schema I can not provide a pl/sql code for you but if you need a code tell me and write me the name of table which stores employees and salary column.

Hope it helps
Iman

Comment: I think the OP just wants to display the before and after values, not store both in the table.

Comment: I have updated the question with my try.. please advise... I need to display the salary before changing it and after changing it

Comment: Alex, I believe Chaz have to store them, otherwise there is not much he can do, we are talking about database, logic is happen to be implemented in database layer niether application logic.

Comment: There isnt other way, you have to store the old value. If anyone knows how to do it without storing the old one, I will be interested to learn. but As you need to have both values( new and old salary) written, you either need to do the print at the changing time and you can not do it whenever you like since the old one does not exist, however if you can implement a temporal model you will be able to do so but in ghat case you still need to save the old salary somewhere.

Comment: Your code will only works if you have multiple record for each employee, for example if for each salary there exists a record, if this is the case and you have all the payments in relevant records your code will work but the first change will always be printed, in case you have one record for esch employee which it is the case as I see, your code will never finishes and you just wrote an infinite loop since you woudnt have two cursor for a single employee, does your code hangs?

Comment: You are welcome Chaz, an answer acceptance will be nice :))

Answer (score 0):

this can be done simply by triggers.

```
create or replace trigger printSal
  before update or insert on employees  
  for each row

declare

begin
  dbms_output.put_line('employee_id =' || emp_ID || ' New Sal=' ||:new.sal|| ' Old Sal=' || :old.sal);
  -- or you can insert these values into another table.
end printSal;
```